# Maximum Likelihood second derivative test

Tags: statistics

[image]

[image]

For part e), I understand that $l(\theta_1,\theta_2)$ is an increasing function of $\theta_2$ for any fixed $\theta_1$ and hence for fixed $\theta_1$, $l(\theta_1,\theta_2)$ is maximised when $\theta_2$ is as large as possible ($=\hat\theta_{2\scriptsize MLE}$). However I don't understand why we only have to focus on $l(\theta_1,\hat\theta_{2\scriptsize MLE})$? $\theta_1$ is now a variable.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a typo in the text. In the equation, $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta_2^2}\ell(\theta_1,\hat\theta_{2MLE})=-\frac{n}{\theta_1^2}$, the left side should have been $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta_1^2}\ell(\theta_1,\hat\theta_{2MLE})$.

The point is that given any $\theta_1$, the maximum value of $\ell(\theta_1,\theta_2)$, where $\theta_2$ is allowed to vary but $\theta_1$ remains fixed, is $\ell(\theta_1,\hat\theta_{2MLE})$. Therefore, the global maximum of $\ell(\theta_1,\theta_2)$, if any exists, must occur at such a point $\ell(\theta_1,\hat\theta_{2MLE})$ for some $\theta_1$. Since $\ell(\theta_1,\theta_2)$ is differentiable with respect to $\theta_1$, we can also say that any local maximum must occur at a point where $\frac{\partial\ell}{\partial\theta_1}=0$, which occurs only at $\theta_1=\hat\theta_{1MLE}$.

Comment: Is there not a difference between any fixed $\theta_1$ and allowing $\theta_1$ to vary?